# Windows search shows wrong drive letter in results

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, windows-registry

When I search folder in Desktop under C:, the search results point me to the right path, but at E: instead.

My computer had its OS cloned to an SSD, and the old OS resides in E: now. Maybe something is wrong with lingering registry keys?

This does not happen when I search from the root of C:.

Comment: Are you sure you are not booting off the old drive still?

Comment: Yes I am sure. The boot time is around 10 seconds which indicates usage of SSD.

Comment: what does `echo %HOMEPATH%`, `echo %HOMEDRIVE%`, and `echo %USERPROFILE%` give you?

Comment: \Users\USER, C:\Users\USER, C: respectively.

Comment: Oddly I remember clearing search index rid me of the problem for a while, then it came back.

Comment: Funny I was going to mention that next. Seem slike it is cached somewhere... Did you do a system restore or anything that might have caused the old state to creep back in?

Comment: I didn't do system restores.

Comment: ok sorry! I am out of ideas.